# why iterator.remove() has been described as optional operation?

Tags: java, iterator

I went through the documentation(http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) of `Iterator.remove()`
there `remove(`) was described as

```
void remove()
```

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
>   by the iterator (optional operation).
>   This method can be called only once
>   per call to next. The behavior of an
>   iterator is unspecified if the
>   underlying collection is modified
>   while the iteration is in progress in
>   any way other than by calling this
>   method.

1. So can anybody tell what "optional" means.
2. Does this affect the robustness of operation?(Like c++ ,it does not guarantee the robustness of the operations.)
3. Why "optional" has been specified categorically here.
4. What does "modification" mean in the second line of documentation

> behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#1: Optional means you can implement it **or** throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`

#2: This operation is optional because sometimes you just don't want your iterator's content to be modified. Or what do you understand by "robustness of operation"?

**EDIT** #4: `behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified`

Normally, you use an iterator by executing

```
List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("Item 1");
c.add("Item 2");
c.add("Item 3");
...
for (Iterator<String> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
  String s = i.next();
  ...
}
```

If you now would want to remove an item *while iterating* through the list, and you would call

```
c.remove("Item 2");
```

this is **not clean**, possibly **corrupts data** in your List/Collection/... and should be **avoided**. Instead, remove() the item **through the iterator**:

```
i.remove();
```

Comment: @Atmocreation:thanx for the explanation,can you please describe the 4 question?

Answer (score 6):

First of all `java.util.Iterator` is an interface i.e. an agreement how classes that implement this interface interract with the rest of the world. It's their responsibility how they'll implement interaface's methods.

If the underlying data structure doesn't allow removal then `remove()` will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. For example, if you are iterating through a result set retrieved from a DB it does make sense not to implement this method.

If you iterate over some collection which is shared between concurrent threads and the other thread modifies the data iterating thread then will return undeterministic results.

Comment: but the fact is every implementing method allows the removal?

Comment: @Boris:thanx for explanation.can you please describe the 4 question?

Answer (score 2):

It is described as being optional because not all collection classes that can give you an iterator implement the `remove()` method in the iterator they return. If the returned iterator doesn't implement it, an `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown.

The normal `java.util.ArrayList`, `java.util.LinkedList` and other standard collection classes all implement the `remove()` method in their iterators, so you can use it safely.

Comment: So the question really is: why is it in the interface in the first place?

Comment: @reinierpost I guess for convenience because many implementations will implement this method. When you design software there are always certain tradeoffs to be made, for example between theoretical "correctness" and practical usefulness, a complex design is never "perfect".