# Java > Filter a Generic Collection

Tags: java, generics

Basically, I'd like to use a `Predicate` to filter a generic (which extends Collection), and then return an instance of the same generic Collection implementation (preferably a new instance) e.g. implement the method signature `F removeNulls(F inputs)`.

I have the following examples, but there are caveats to each (`removeNulls4` is probably the closest to what I'm trying to achieve):

## Caveats

#### removeNulls1:

- the returned list may(/will) not be an instance of `F` (requires casting)

#### removeNulls2:

- the implementation of `F` may not have an empty constructor
- use of the `forReturn` object [is not thread safe (if run in parallel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755993/782034)

#### removeNulls3:

- modifies the original list
- is reinventing the wheel/not parallelisable (would prefer to use the `filter` method)
- `Iterator.remove()` [can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536273/why-iterator-remove-has-been-described-as-optional-operation)

#### removeNulls4:

- modifies the original list

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class QuickTest<I, F extends Collection<I>> {

    Predicate<I> removeNullsPredicate = x -> x != null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public F removeNulls1(F inputs) throws Exception {
        return (F) inputs.stream().filter(removeNullsPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public F removeNulls2(F inputs) throws Exception {
        F forReturn = (F) inputs.getClass().newInstance();
        inputs.stream().filter(removeNullsPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> forReturn));
        return forReturn;
    }

    public F removeNulls3(F inputs) throws Exception {
        Iterator<I> iter = inputs.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            I next = iter.next();
            boolean test = removeNullsPredicate.test(next);
            if (!test){
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        return inputs;
    }

    public F removeNulls4(F inputs) throws Exception {
        List<I> forRemoval = inputs.stream().filter(removeNullsPredicate.negate())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        inputs.removeAll(forRemoval);
        return inputs;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say creating a new instance of the collection is an implementation detail which should not be handled by generic code. I'd think about either extending the Collection interface to force the implementation to provide a custom Collector or forcing the 'user' of the predicate to supply a Collector by any other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a `Supplier<F>` as an argument:

```
public F removeNulls(F inputs, Supplier<F> factory) {
    return inputs.stream().filter(removeNullsPredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(factory));
}
```

Then simply call:

```
List<I> nonNulls = removeNulls(inputs, ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: This is the best approximation realistically possible.  +1.